# List of broken apps on Android 5.0

Tags: applications

I had some apps installed on my Sony Xperia Z external SD Card.

Now the SD card is damaged for some reason, and my mobile won't show those apps. 
Instead of each app icon, I get a green Droid icon with a little red sd-card icon on its top left corner. Obviously meaning that those apps are missing and can not be loaded from SD Card.

Is there a way to get a list of those apps, so that I would re-install them from Play Store? Even groupId would be enough (e.g. com.example.foe) and I will do the search manually to figure out all those missing apps.

Thanks!

Comment: `adb shell` `cd /system/data`  `pm list  packages` (should  work) or `cd /system/app`  `pm list packages`

Comment: Thanks @esQmo but this lists only the installed apps. I think the apps on the SD card are not considered installed anymore. However the Sony launcher is able to fetch them somewhere from some resource. I wish to be able to get a list of those apps?

Comment: if an app installed on the SD card and it is removed, the app still appear on the app list and even on the desktop.

Comment: Appears on the desktop but not in the app list provided by that command :(

Comment: so you see have the app name you need?

Comment: No I don't. I only see list of already installed apps.

Comment: Oh, but in the app list, they should appear with their icons greyed out.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying to explain. So in the app drawer and on the desktop; They are kinda disabled.
If I run the `pm list package`, I don't see them in the given list.

Comment: If you put the SD card in a computer or another phone?

Comment: And what about the list in Settings -> Apps?

Comment: @owlswipe the SD is corrupted, I can not read it using any other device.
And the list in Settings is the list of currently available and installed apps, not the list of apps previously on SD card and with broken shortcut on desktop..

Comment: Hmm...How about in the Play Store?

Comment: @owlswipe in Play Store I have under "Installed" the list of currently installed apps not including the broken shortcuts, and under "All" the list of all apps installed since ever, which is too huge to filter them.

Comment: Hmm. Do you have a backup of your phone? And if so, on what service?

Comment: @owlswipe Only the normal Google Account backup, nothing else

Comment: I also had some manual apps backup on the SD card itself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, found what I was looking for.

All apps that were stored in the SD card, are located inside this file:

`/data/data/com.sonyericsson.home/shared_prefs/home_external_storage_apps_pref.xml`

Thanks for all contributed comments!